# HttpWebRequest reeading from a String

Tags: c#, httpwebrequest, browser, httpwebresponse

I am creating a simple web browser in C#. I have been instructed not to use the webbrowser class provided, so I have to code everything. I am struggling to load the page from  my url. Here's my code:

```
private void toolStripButton5_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        url = "http://" + toolStripTextBox1.Text;
        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
        HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
        Stream pageStream = response.GetResponseStream();
        StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(pageStream);
    }
```

StripButton5 corresponds to my navigate button in my form. The problem i'm having is when I type the address like www.google.com. the page just hangs and doesn't load. Any suggestions appreciated.

Comment: You have to do something with 'response'. What code comes after this? i.e. You have the response, now what do you want to do with it.

Comment: What does "page just hangs" mean? if by "page" you mean the response body then as DeeMac said you need to do something with StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream())

Comment: @DeeMac  I have edited the OP with my updated code after the response. I have added a stream & a streamreader. The page still doesnt load.

Comment: @AlexK. by page I mean my browser doesnt load the address. I have updated the code and tried your suggestion but still doesnt work.

Comment: @user2268970 - now what are you going to do with 'reader'? I might have the wrong idea here, but you have your web response in a variable, now you must do something with that variable. Or at least during debugging check the value of 'reader' is as you'd expect so that you know this code so far is working.

Comment: @DeeMac Thanks I needed to add more stuff for the browser to display the page. I have updated the code.

Comment: No problem. You got there in the end.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Had to encode and then read the HTML then get the browser to display it in html.

```
 private void toolStripButton5_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
   url = "http://" + toolStripTextBox1.Text;
   HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
   HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
   Stream pageStream = response.GetResponseStream();
   StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(pageStream,Encoding.Default);
   string s = reader.ReadToEnd();
   webBrowser1.DocumentText = s;
 }
```

Comment: Don't forget to dispose the request/response/stream